# Redirect all request to a folder to a webpage in IIS 7

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I need to redirect all the request to following URL to another php file 
Eg :

```
http://www.example.com/images/profile_images/thumb/mypic.jpg
to 
http://www.example.com/index.php/image/profile_images/mypic.jpg/thumb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `web.config` in the folder `thumb` with following lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>


    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="original2fake" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.+)$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/index.php/image/profile_images/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```